# Html.ListBoxFor Object reference not set to an instance of an object Error

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, listbox

I am using view model to display a dropdownlist and i am also trying to get the value of the selected list, here is my view model

```
public class CreateJobViewModel
{
    public int[] SelectedIndustriesIds { get; set; }
    public IList<SelectListItem> IndustriesList { get; set; }
}
```

My controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var industryList = repository.GetAllIndustries();

    var model = new CreateJobViewModel
    {
        IndustriesList = industryList.Select(i => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = i.IndustryId.ToString(),
            Text = i.Name
        }).ToList()
    };

    return View("~/Views/Dashboard/Job/Create.cshtml", model);
}
```

My post controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(CreateJobViewModel model)
{

    try
    {
        var job = new Job()
        {
            Title = "hi",
            EmploymentHourId = 1,
            LocationId = 1,
            Salary = 50,
            SalaryPeriodId = 1,
            PostCode = 2131,
            Role = "world",
            Description = "hello",
            IsPublished = false,
            ShiftId = 1,
            WorkDayId = 1,
            NumberOfPosition = 5,
            Meal = false,
            SecondYearVisa = true,
            Sponsorship = true,
            Accommodation = true,
            DurationId = 1,
            IndustryExperiencePeriod = 5,
            Id = User.Identity.GetUserId(),


        };
        foreach (int id in model.SelectedIndustriesIds)
        {
            var industry = repository.Industry(id);
            job.Industries.Add(industry);
        }



        foreach (int id in model.SelectedSpecialRequirementsId)
        {
            var special = repository.SpecialRequirement(id);
            job.SpecialRequirements.Add(special);
        }

        repository.AddJob(job);

        return RedirectToAction("Create");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View("~/Views/Dashboard/Job/Create.cshtml");
    }
}
```

Every time i try to submit the selected value, i get Object reference not set to an instance of an object Error on the following line in my view:

```
@model Taw.WebUI.Models.CreateJobViewModel

@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedIndustriesIds, Model.IndustriesList) -- here i get the error
```

Any reason why?

Comment: Do you get error when it load first time or only get when you post ?

Comment: I suspect this is because your getting an exception in the POST method and in the catch block your returning the view. When you return the view, you first need to reassign the value of `IndustriesList` otherwise its `null` and the exception on the view is thrown.

Comment: @Stephen yea there is some problem with my post action but i don't know what it is

Comment: Add a breakpoint and step through it. But to solve your immediate problem just assign the value of `IndustriesList` again before you return it. As a side note `public SelectList IndustriesList { get; set; }` and `model.IndustriesList = new SelectList(industryList, "IndustryId", "Name");` is a lot easier

Comment: @Stephen thanks, I figured out the problem, its in my binding, I created a new custom model binder but do you know how i can get all SelectedIndustriesIds values in the custom model binder? i tried var industries = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("SelectedIndustriesIds").AttemptedValue.ToArray() but that is not working

Comment: Why do you need to create a custom model binder? I cant see anything in your code to suggest you need one.

Comment: @Stephen I want to bind multiple industries to a single job, just want to separate them, don't want to do everything in my controller, looks messy and hard to maintain

Comment: Are you trying to call your database within your custom model binder to do `job.Industries.Add(industry)`? If so I strongly recommend against it. That's not the responsibility of the `ModelBinder`, not to mention almost impossible to unit test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you submit the form your throwing an exception (confirmed in the comments) and in the `catch` block you are returning the view, which throws the exception you are seeing because `Model.IndustriesList` is null. You need to re-assign the value before you return the view.

Since you need to assign `SelectList`s in the GET method and in the POST method if you return the view, I tend to re-factor this to a separate method to keep the controller code a bit cleaner. Note the following code is based on your model property being `public SelectList IndustriesList { get; set; }` which is a bit simpler than building `IList<SelectListItem>`

```
private void ConfigureViewModel(CreateJobViewModel model)
{
  var industryList = repository.GetAllIndustries();
  model.IndustriesList = new SelectList(industryList, "IndustryId", "Name")
  // any other common stuff
}
```

and then in the action methods

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  var model = new CreateJobViewModel();
  ConfigureViewModel(model);
  return View(model);
}

public ActionResult Create(CreateJobViewModel model)
{
  try
  {
    ....
  }
  catch
  {
    ConfigureViewModel(model);
    return View(model);
  }
}
```

Note its also good practice to test if the model is valid before attempting to save it

```
public ActionResult Create(CreateJobViewModel model)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    ConfigureViewModel(model);
    return View(model); // return the view so the user can correct validation errors
  }
  ....
```